# Conditional statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query,

```
SET @theYear = 2017;
SET @theTeam = null;

SELECT 
    SUM(growth), r.theYear
FROM
    Reports r
WHERE
        r.theYear = @theYear
        AND (@theTeam IS NULL
        OR r.team = @theTeam)
GROUP BY theYear
ORDER BY theYear;
```

The above works fine if a team is mentioned or is null. What I want to do now is include all teams should the variable `@theTeam` be null.

I am trying something like the following,

```
SELECT 
    IF(@theTeam,
        (SELECT 
                SUM(growth), r.theYear
            FROM
                Reports r
            WHERE
                r.theYear = @theYear
                AND r.team = @theTeam
            GROUP BY theYear
            ORDER BY theYear),
        (SELECT 
                SUM(growth), r.theYear
            FROM
                Reports r
            WHERE
             r.theYear = @theYear
            GROUP BY theYear
            ORDER BY theYear));
```

It fails with `Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)` I am using **MYSQL 8.0.17** Would there be a another way to do this?

Comment: If a subquery is used as an expression, it can only return one value, not a table. You can't put a whole table in a `SELECT` list.

Comment: If you want to select from different tables depending on a variable, you need to write a procedure to execute queries conditionally.

Comment: @Barmar it is actually one table. I have edited my question to reflect that

Comment: In that case why doesn't the original query work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(growth), r.theYear
FROM
    Reports r
WHERE
        r.theYear = @theYear
        AND r.team <=> IFNULL(@theTeam, r.team)
GROUP BY theYear
ORDER BY theYear;
```

When `@theTeam` is null it will compare `r.team` with itself, which is always true.

It also uses the `<=>` null-safe comparison operator, which will work when `r.team` is null.

Comment: The comparison is not *always* true.  It fails if `r.team` is `NULL`.  That is why an explicit `NULL` comparison is preferred.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Good catch, I've switched to the `<=>` operator.

Comment: @Barmar I am getting Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_bin,NONE) for operation '<=>'. Looks like a collation issue

Comment: `SET @theTeam = CONVERT('teamName' USING utf8mb4_bin);`